# Understanding the integral formula of a centroid of a subset $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus

Reading the Wikipedia article on centroids, the author mentions that a centroid of a subset $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ can be computed by the integral

$\large C = \frac {\int x g(x) dx} {\int g(x) dx}$ integrated overall of $\mathbb{R}^n$,

where $g(x)$ is a density function on this subset.

From what I understand $C \in \mathbb{R}^n$, but integrals over regions give real numbers, so I'm a bit confused here.

For instance suppose we just took a rectangle $X = Rect = \{(x,y,z)| x \in [-1,-1],y \in[-1,1],z \in [-2,2]\}$, what would this integral be?

Thanks.

Comment: The integral in the numerator is a vector. (BTW, $g(x)$ is the *density*, not the char. func.)

Comment: @metamorphy, this might seem strange, but I've never seen the output of an integral be a vector, can you elaborate?

Comment: The *integrand* is $g(x)$ [which is scalar] multiplied by $x$ [which is a vector]. Thus we're integrating a vector. (Think of it the coordinate way: each coordinate gets integrated independently.)

Comment: The integral of a vector will be computed componentwise

Comment: @metamorphy is my answer what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some helpful comments, to answer my own question, you integrate componentwise, so in my example for the $x$ component of the centroid, as per the formula, in the numerator you would have the triple integral

$\int_{z \in [-2,2]} \int_{y \in[-1,1]} \int_{x \in [-1,-1]} x g(\vec{x}) dx dy dz$